# Who is Sister Irene in "Going Down" by Freddie King?

Tags: lyrics, meaning, blues, backstory

I'm working on *Going Down* by Freddie King and I don't understand the reference of this sentence:

> I'm going back to Chattanooga and sleep on sister Irene's porch

I can't find any reference from my European point of view. Who's sister Irene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with no certainty, I'd guess at the nun who ran the children's home, when he was young.

His character is a homeless man, a hobo - presumably he had his best times back there, where he was looked after as a child.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is the below,of course cannot be sure...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sister_Mary_Irene_FitzGibbon